# How do I make the form don't do anything at all if Submitted on blank?

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation, forms

How do I make don't do anything if a user clicks submit and he didn't write anything? I mean not show a message or anything just don't do anything.

I'm just starting to learn HTML and far from pulling off anything with PHP... I don't know how difficult is to do this so idk. Thanks for the help anyway

```
<textarea class="question-box" style="width:97%;" cols="20" rows="4"  id="question-box-' . $questionformid . '" name="title" onfocus="if(this.value == \'\'){this.value = \'\';}" onblur="if(this.value == \'\'){this.value = \'\';}"></textarea>

<table class=sample width=100% style="width:100%;">
<tr style="width:100%;">
<td width=480px>

<input type="hidden" class="ubicacion" style="width:60%; font-weight:bold; border-color:white; background:white; color:white" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?> " name="question" onfocus="if(this.value == \'\'){this.value = \'\';}" onblur="if(this.value == \'\'){this.value = \'\';}" /></p>
```

Comment: I think you would need JavaScript for that

Comment: If not doing anything really is the default action, use a `<button>` instead of `<input type=submit>` and apply JS for actual submitting.

Comment: @mario: But what about people with JS disabled?  Shouldn't they be able to submit and be validated on the server-side?

Comment: @JonahBron: Interesting meta topic. But as one of the crazy people with selective JS enabling, I would say broken sites are mostly expected if you configure your browser that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="if (document.getElementById('s').value.length < 1) return false;">
...
```

The simplest solution possible that I'm aware of.

But remember, Javascript validation is only for the convenience of the user; it must always be double-checked on the server-side.

Comment: Can I ask you something else? I want to make it work on another one but I'm not sure how. Could you check it and tell me? I just copied it to the question body

Comment: @Lisandro: All you have to do is add the `onsubmit` attribute to your form, and change the id in `getElementById` to the correct value.

Comment: +1 for always double-check on the server. If the server receives the form submission and it's all empty it can simply redisplay the original (empty) form page without adding any error message to it.

Comment: I believe `if (document.getElementById('s').value)` works just fine... and it is even simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

you need javascript. something like :

```
<script language="javascript">
function validateForm( form )
{
    result = false;
    //validate user input ...
    return result;
}
</script>
<form ... onSubmit='return validateForm( this );'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need form validation.  While there are many ways to do this with Javascript may I suggest JQuery?  This will enhance your HTML pages, though it will give you more to learn (which is good).

See here:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

And look at the demos.  If this does not suffice look at jquery form validation on Google.